# Does it hold that $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n(1-p^{-i}) \geq {(1-p^{-1}})^2$?

Tags: combinatorics, upper-lower-bounds

I was trying to find a lower bound for the product $$\prod\limits_{i=1}^n(1-p^{-i})$$ and it seems that the following inequality holds but I was not able to prove it: for every natural $n$, $p$,

$$\prod_{i=1}^n(1-p^{-i}) \geq {(1-p^{-1}})^2$$

Comment: So $(1-1/p^2)(1-1/p^3)\cdots\ge (1-1/p)$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics StackExchange! The user community is more comfortable when posters include more context, in particular, your attempts at solution. Can you see the inequality works for any special values of $n$ or $p$?

Comment: @anon so $\left(1 + \frac1{p}\right) \left(1 - \frac1{p^3}\right) \cdots \ge 1$ ($p\neq 1$).

Comment: @dantopa I used a graphing calculator to verify it and it seems to work but I still don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider some real number $x$ in $[0,\frac12]$. For every $n\geqslant1$, $$\color{red}{\frac{x^n}{1-x^n}}\leqslant1$$ Using the expansion $$\log(1-t)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{t^n}n$$ one sees that $$\sum_{i=2}^\infty\log(1-x^i)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{i=2}^\infty\frac{x^{in}}n=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}n\color{red}{\frac{x^n}{1-x^n}}\geqslant-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}n=\log(1-x)$$ Exponentiating both sides and multiplying everything by $(1-x)$, one gets $$\prod_{i=1}^\infty(1-x^i)\geqslant(1-x)^2$$ which is equivalent to (a strengthening of) the desired inequality for every $p\geqslant2$.